# User seems not assigned to the role after SAML authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, keycloak, saml-2.0, tomcat9

I am trying to setup SAML authentication on Apache Tomcat 9.0.24. I am using  keycloak-saml-tomcat-adapter-dist-7.0.0 plugin that should authenticate against KeyCloak standalone server (v 7.0.0).

I have set up the usual role mappings in web.xml, like:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>role0</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
   <display-name>Security constraint for the /ktc folder</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>/ktc page</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/ktc</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>role0</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The docker machines are finding each other, and when I try to access the protected resource /ktc, the attempt is intercepted and I am directed to the keycloak server to login. If I supply the invalid credentials, the login attempt is correctly rejected. Further, if I supply valid credentials, I am redirected back to my Tomcat website.

Here, unfortunately, Tomcat is not passing me to the protected resource. If I try to access it again, second time I am redirected back after only something quickly flashing on the screen, without presenting a login form to me. From this I suspect I am actually authenticated, but do not get the expected role assigned. The keycloak server event logs also show me as being logged in, while they do not tell how successfully and which roles got assigned.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I managed to find where the problem is, up to the community to decide to keep this or not.

Answer (score 1):

The POST endpoint configured on the KeyCloak authentication server must end with /saml and not point to any POST endpoint of the existing servlet inside the Tomcat. Only then the KeyCloak valve will intercept it.